# Difference Between Fear and Fright

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

I learn that as a noun *fright* is a derivative of *fear*.
What's the difference between these two?
I read that fright is more intense than fear, is it true?

I also read the explanation [here](https://wikidiff.com/fright/fear#:%7E:text=As%20nouns%20the%20difference%20between,or%20perceived%20danger%20or%20threat.), but I can't quite understand the difference in the usage.

Answer (score 2):

*Fear* may be an ongoing state resulting from living in dangerous times or knowing that your future is particularly uncertain.

If something gives you a *fright*, it is a sudden perception of immediate threat, such as thinking you hear an intruder in the night.

Comment: Frightfully good explanation.